# Vaadin Flow: How to use Select from Java

Tags: vaadin, html-select, vaadin-flow

the Vaadin [documentation states](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-select) that it has support for a compontent called `Select` using Java.

How do you access it?
I cant find any corresponding class.
Not even its install section mentions it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the following dependency to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-select-flow</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Note that Vaadin 12 had only a front-end component and not a Java component for Select. In Vaadin 13, which is today beta, the Java integration was also added. If you use Vaadin 13.0.0.beta1, then can use it out-of-the-box. If you are using an earlier version, like Vaadin 12, then you have to add the dependency Mehdi mentioned explicitly.

Comment: Well that was unexptectedly easy. Thank you